# Finding the Beginning of a string in C

Tags: c, loops, c-strings

To solve a question, I am looking for a way to stop a loop after it has reached the beginning of the string, assuming the loop starts from the end and decrements, is there an alternative way to do this without finding the length of the string first and decrementing till the number is zero? 
Please keep in mind the only functions I can use are malloc, free and write.

Comment: What do you mean by "beginning"? Don't you have a pointer to the start of the string?

Comment: No pointer to the beginning of the string, only to the null byte of the end? Any constraints as for the _content_ of the string?

Comment: How do you find the end without counting?

Comment: @diola.O For starters you can not find a string end without using the function strlen or a loop.

Comment: If you only have a pointer to the end of a string and no other info then it is not possible to find the start of the string.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: You can definitely find a C-style string's ed withou using `strlen()`...

Comment: I think there's more to this question than you've told us, like where did this question come from, and what is the complete and exact wording of the question.

Comment: What do you need this for? There's probably a better way to do it, without having to iterate to the start of the string

Comment: If code has a _string_, it knows the beginning.  Iterate a pointer `p` from the end until it matches the beginning.  Better yet, post the code you tried that failed.

Comment: The beginning of a string with a given terminator is not, in general, a well-defined concept.  A string of length n can very naturally be viewed as an overlay of n+1 strings, each shorter than the next by one character, all sharing a terminator.  If you start at the terminator, then, how do you know which of those strings to choose?  "The longest one" is *not* a clear choice, even if there were a way to recognize it.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible, because there is nothing special about a string's contents at the beginning. C strings have a "sentinel value" at their *end* - `'\0'` - but the first character, and the byte in memory before the first character, can have any value.

Answer (score 1):

> is there an alternative way to do this without finding the length of the string first and decrementing till the number is zero?

Apparently you already know where the end of the string is.  I suppose you must have a pointer to the terminator character, since you think you do not know the string length.

If finding the length of the string is a viable option at all, however, then you must *already know* where the beginning is, too.  And if you know where the beginning is and you know where the end is, then you *already know* the length: it is `end - beginning`.  But you do not need to keep a separate counter to iterate backward from the end of a string to the beginning, supposing that you do know where both the end and the beginning are.  You can simply use pointer comparisons instead.  For example:

```
int count_a_backwards(const char *beginning, const char *end) {
    int count = 0;

    for (const char *c = end; c > beginning; ) {
        if (*--c == 'a') count += 1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

If in fact you do not know where the beginning of the string is, however, then you cannot identify it at all, at least not in the general case.  Perhaps you can recognize the beginning if you have some kind of prior knowledge about the string's contents, or about its alignment, or some such, but in general, the beginning of a string cannot be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

> Please keep in mind the only functions I can use are malloc, free and
>   write.

If you are using the function `malloc` then the function returns pointer to the first byte of the allocated memory. So if the allocated array will  contain a string then its beginning will be known.

The task is to find the end of the string.

You can use either the standard C function `strlen` or write your own loop that will find the end of the stored string.

So if you have two pointers, one that points to the beginning of a string and the second that points to the end of the same string then to traverse the string in the reverse order is not a hard work.

Pay attention to that if you have a character array that contains a string like this

```
char s[] = "Hello";
```

then the expressions s, s + 1, s + 2 and so on all points to a string correspondingly "Hello", "ello", "llo" and so on.

You could find the beginning of a string having a pointer to its end provided that the first element of the array contains a unique symbol that is a sentinel value. However in general this is a very rare case.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how you can traverse a string in the reverse order without using standard C string functions except a function that places a string in a dynamically allocated array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 12 };

    char *s = malloc( N );

    strcpy( s, "Hello World" );

    puts( s );

    char *p = s;

    while ( *p ) ++p;

    while ( p != s ) putchar( *--p );
    putchar( '\n');

    free( s );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World
dlroW olleH
```